# Regular Expression to replace one letter surrounded with dashes

Tags: c#, regex

I try to replace a specific letter surrounded by one or two dashes with another letter

**Examples**:
modif-i-ed    => modifyed (-i- is replaced with y)

a-im  => eim (a- is replaced with e)

I tried

```
Regex.Replace(word, "-?([a-zA-Z])-", new_letter)
```

But it generates for example `modiyyed` for the first example.

Comment: use this `-[a-zA-Z]-`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: That won't work on the second example.

Comment: @TimPietzcker oh.. yes i didnt noticed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that once the first `-` becomes optional, there are 2 matches inside `modif-i-ed`: `f-` and `i-`. Thus, there are two replacements.

I suggest matching and capturing the letters before the `-X-` pattern and then return them as is in the Match evaluator, and use `-?[a-z]-` to match and then replace:

```
(\B[a-z](?=-))|-?[a-z]-
```

C#:

```
var myLetter = "y";
var str = " modif-i-ed  a-im  y-i-eld";
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\B[a-z](?=-))|-?[a-z]-",
      m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : myLetter);
Console.WriteLine(res); // => modifyed  yim  yyeld
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/hxzmVz)

Comment: You don't really need the second one.

Comment: I know, but it is logical. Just to show that the letter must be a whole word. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: As I try it in C# winforms, it doesn't work, it doesn't change the input word!

Comment: @Ahmad: Do you try with the code above? Do you use verbatim string literals? I added a [**working code IDEONE demo**](http://ideone.com/nmIJzH).

Comment: **@Downvoter:** Please always leave the downvote reasoning with such answers as mine. **It is neither a code only, nor "try-this" answer.** It is working and tested, and double-checked, and explained.

Comment: It seems doesn't work for `y-i-eld` when `-i-` should be replaced with `e`, it generates `eeeld`

Comment: Ok, you will need a callback. I updated the answer to show how it can be done.